# MySQL query errors with "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm performing the following query and it seems I have an issue right where I'm doing the `convert(aes_decrypt)` part as the query was working fine before I added it in. I know it's something small but can't quite seem to get the statement correct.

Missing quotes or wrong quotes? I just can't see it..

```
$db->query("SELECT 
`users`.`name` AS `users`.`name` ,
convert(aes_decrypt(`users`.`email`,".$salt.") using utf8 AS `users`.`email` ,
`users`.`address` AS `users`.`address`
FROM `users`");
```

The exact error I'm receiving is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.`name` ,convert(aes_decrypt(`users`.`email`,MySecretSa' at line
>   1

Comment: it's strange: *`users`.`name` AS `users`.`name`*

Comment: ".$salt." it should be, '$salt'

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket `)` not entirely sure where, but maybe here `convert(aes_decrypt(`users`.`email`,".$salt."))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was indeed missing a bracket but it goes after `utf8` - still not working though. Thanks

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Nope still no luck.

Comment: Change *users.name AS users.name* to  *users.name AS name* and same for other aliases

Comment: change ``users`.`name` AS `users`.`name` ,`to ``users`.`name` AS `name` ,` and it should work.

Comment: @sectus Yeah I usually use `users.name` but some crud stuff is adding the AS even though I'm not changing the name of it.

Comment: Try `SELECT `users`.`name` AS alias_name` the error is coming from there. `right syntax to use near '.name ,convert...`

Comment: Tried that as well but no luck. It's now displaying  `Unknown column 'MySecretSa' in 'field list'`

Comment: I think you should start again - with the current query, and the current error message. This thread is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias names are user defined. Qualifiers on them is meaning less and not supported.

```
select users.column_name as users.column_name 
  from users -- this syntax is not correct
```

If you want just the same name as column name, omit alias name.

```
select column_name from table_name
```

And if you want explicit column/expression alias names don't use table qualifiers.

```
select column_name as alias_name
     , col1 * col2 as expression_alias 
  from table_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So now I have this error: `Unknown column 'MySecretSa' in 'field list'` and my new statement is: `SELECT name,convert(aes_decrypt(email,MySecretSa) using utf8) AS email,address FROM users`

Comment: What is `MySecretSa`? Is it not a `column_name` in the table `users`. If not so, then use a literal string instead.

Comment: it's the value of my `$salt`. How should my statement be updated?

Comment: Put it in single quotes. You better use Prepared Statement in PHP

Comment: Ok so that's now sorted, thank you. It's now causing this error: `Undefined index: users.name Undefined index: users.email....` sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Are they on **aliases** defined. If so, as suggested, remove `'users.'` after `'as'` keyword.

Comment: No idea what that means. The statement output I currently have is `SELECT name,convert(aes_decrypt(email,MySecretSa) using utf8) AS email,address FROM users`

Comment: Query sounds good. Unless we know error stack root, I can't predict.

Comment: @DT.DTDG Why are you using `AS email,address`? There should only be one such as `AS email`, *theoretically*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: `Address` must be another column in the table. `As email` is one part of the query and `address` another field in select list

Comment: @Fred-ii-: BTW, OP however has syntax error in the query. It should be `convert( ... using utf8 )`. Closing brace is missing

Comment: @Ravinder Updated that missing closing brace about an hour ago :) and `address` is indeed another column

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,it's strange: users.name AS users.name

The error in the second users.name  is wrong.

can make it like this

```
$db->query("SELECT 
`users`.`name` AS `user_name` ,
convert(aes_decrypt(`users`.`email`,".$salt.") using utf8 AS `users`.`email` ,
`users`.`address` AS `users`.`address`
FROM `users`");
```

Or you can eliminate  like this

```
$db->query("SELECT 
`users`.`name`,
convert(aes_decrypt(`users`.`email`,".$salt.") using utf8 AS `users`.`email` ,
`users`.`address` AS `users`.`address`
FROM `users`");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql query:-

```
$db->query("SELECT 
`users`.`name` AS name ,
CONVERT( aes_decrypt(`users`.`email`, '$salt') USING utf8) AS email ,
`users`.`address` AS address
FROM `users`");
```

Comment: Thanks, so now I have this error: `Unknown column 'MySecretSa' in 'field list'` and my new statement is: `SELECT name,convert(aes_decrypt(email,MySecretSa) using utf8) AS email,address FROM users`

Comment: What is it in `$salt` ?

Comment: Plain text "MySecretSa". Now having an issue of `Undefined index: users.name Undefined index: users.email....`

Comment: Have you used `AES_ENCRYPT` before inserting `email` in database ?, Please check this link:- http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/encryption-and-compression-functions/aes_decrypt().php

Comment: @AkshayPãghdÂr: Error is not in encryption/decryption, I believe

Comment: have you used `AES_ENCRYPT('emailID', 'MySecretSa')` ?

Comment: Will you please add your `table structure` & `sample data` in your question ?

Comment: Encryption is perfectly ok and `AES_ENCRYPT` is used prior to the Db insert.